# How to return a character pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, character

I'm new to C.
I'm trying to return a character pointer >> A pointer that points to a single character value.
I know I can simply return a character but I want to learn how to return a character pointer pointing to a single character value.

```
char * returnPointerToCharacter(){
    char s = 's';
    char * pointerToS = &s;
    return pointerToS;
}

int main()
{
//         This code below works  
    char h = 'h';
    char * pointerToH = &h;
    printf("%c \n", *pointerToH);

//         This code below doesn't work                
    char * pointerToS = returnPointerToCharacter();
    printf("%c \n", *pointerToS);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tip: You must *allocate* pointer values you're returning unless you can express them in terms of pointers to data that was pre-existing. `s` only exists when that function's running. It's invalid the instant it exits.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that char s is on the stack, and gets popped from the stack, so you're returning a pointer to a destructed element.

If you just want a function that returns a char pointer, you could try something simple:

```
char * returnPointerToCharacter(char *s){
    return s;
}
...// Do stuff
char f;
char * pointerToS = returnPointerToCharacter(&f);
```

Comment: My bad, it's one of those mornings. I hope this is more appropriate for C

Comment: Removing a value from stack is popping, not pushing.

Comment: Correct, saying it gets "pushed off" the stack is a colloquialism and imprecise, it'd be more accurate to say it gets "removed" from the stack, or as you said "popped" from the stack. Updated my answer =)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to return a character pointer

Your code *does* return a character pointer.  But it also commits a cardinal sin: it returns a pointer to an object whose lifetime ends with the completion of the function call.  The resulting pointer is therefore useless to caller.

There are several alternatives.  Often, if one is going to return a pointer, one dynamically allocates the object to which it is to point.  Dynamically allocated objects live until they are explicitly freed.  For your particular purposes, however, I would suggest making the function's local variable `static`, which exactly means that it lives and retains its last-set value for the entire life of the program:

```
char * returnPointerToCharacter(){
    static char s = 's';

    return &s;
}
```

Comment: Could you some how use malloc to return the character pointer instead of using static?

Comment: There's nothing new to show, @SalmanAhmed.  Whether you obtain your pointer by dynamic memory allocation or by application of the `&` operator, a pointer is a value similar to any other.  You can store it in a variable or pass it to or return it from a function in exactly the same way you do a value of any other type.